# Ionic 2 - Push data from server to app

Tags: ionic2

I have an app in Ionic 2 with a Rails backend. I wanna do some calls to my app (kinda like uber flow). I tried to use OneSignal as push server to send data to my app through notification. However, sometimes the notification gets on a queue that can last 5 minutes or more... which is very bad for me, 'cause I wanna response from the app in a short time. So thought I could do some calls from the app to my server from time to time (every 5 seconds, for example) to check if there's some new call. Is that the best way to do that? And if yes, where on my app should I do that, since it's global? app.component is ok?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices. You can either call your API every x seconds and ask for changes or you can use WebSockets, which allows you to push data from the server to the client instantly.

Both ways have advantages and disadvantages, especially when scaling your app.

If you want to have a "real-time" feeling in our app, I would recommend using WebSockets. I have never worked with Rails before, but in node.js socket.io is quite easy to get started with.

About the location of the code in your app: In either case I would create a service/provider that contains your logic and then require that provider in your app.component.ts

Comment: Great answer! Gonna check about websockets and see what's better for me. Thank you!